# flutter_reactive_ble scanned devices not including device UUIDs

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32

```
_scanStream = flutterReactiveBle
          .scanForDevices(withServices: <Uuid>[]).listen((device) {
        _foundBleUARTDevices.add(device);
        for (var element in _foundBleUARTDevices) {
          print(
              "${element.serviceUuids}---${element.name}---${element.id}---${element.serviceData}---${element.rssi}");
        }
```

I am using the above code snippet to scan for BLE devices and on discovering and printing them out, the UUID is an empty list, and when I try to scan with a specific UUID no device is found. I am using ESP32 as the BLE device and android as the platform to run/debug the app

Answer (score 1):

after waiting for hours, I got no answer from anyone and I had to keep trying, and what I find out is that I can actually connect to the BLE device without the Service UUID but just the id which is the BLE device mac address I think.

I used the below snippet to establish the connection:

```
  void _connectToDevice() {
    // We're done scanning, we can cancel it
    // _scanStream.cancel();
    // Let's listen to our connection so we can make updates on a state change
    Stream<ConnectionStateUpdate> _currentConnectionStream = flutterReactiveBle
        .connectToAdvertisingDevice(
            id: _ubiqueDevice.id,
            prescanDuration: const Duration(seconds: 3),
            withServices: <Uuid>[]);
    _currentConnectionStream.listen((event) {
      print(":::::::: ${event.connectionState.name}");
    });
  }

so I will now proceed to see how I can read and write to the characteristics, i hope someone find this helpful
```